# svn post-commit call to jenkins build http failure

Tags: svn, jenkins, subversive

When I attempt to call a Jenkins build via the post-commit script svn returns an access denied failure.  Using the directions at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin my first attempts followed with the specific configuration Jenkins was in.

First Jenkins configuration:
[x] Enable Security => Jenkins’s own user database
[x] Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits (w/ & w/out *Default Crumb Issuer* enabled)
This returned

```
Error: Connecting to SERVER_IP:8080... failed: Permission denied.
```

After this failed several times using various **wget** options such as http-user, user, http-password, password, etc I changed the Jenkins server configuration to stop using the **CSRF**.  This also failed.  I passed the user API token, job API token, and plain user-name/password.  When these failed I attempted to call the jobs from the commandline itself with **wget** and amazingly it succeeded.

Current Jenkins Configuration:
All security options disabled.  I"m not using users and I am not using tokens or anything.

The SVN post-commit file only has one command in it.

```
wget http://SERVER_IP:8080/job/JOB_trunk/build?token=BUILD --tries=2 --timeout=2
```

This works from the command line.  Jenkins builds the job.  Jenkins does not run the build as the user I provide **wget** with **--http-user** and **--http-password**.  While it doesn't build as the user I want it at least builds, with and without the **?token** option.

If I run the post-commit hook using `sudo /var/svn/JOB/hooks/post-commit` the Jenkins build runs.

Every time I make a commit to svn, the post-commit hook is run and attempts to trigger the Jenkins build and I get back the below error.

```
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:  
Error: --2013-08-21 21:36:37--  http://SERVER_IP:8080/job/JOB_trunk/build?token=BUILD  
Error: Connecting to SERVER_IP:8080... failed: Permission denied.
```

While I can build things manually, poll for svn changes, or etc... I am interested in only triggering builds from the post-commit hook.

The SVN server is running on CentOS6.
Jenkins is running on Win7.

For testing purposes I tried to trigger the build by using the **su** command from the script and continued to have problems.  It successfully builds the job if I run the script from the command line, it does not trigger the build when the svn commit triggers the hook.

```
/bin/su -c `wget http://SERVER_IP:8080/job/JOB_trunk/build --tries=2 --timeout=2
```

Any insight as to what is happening would make me a very happy person and extraordinarily thankful after a week and hours of attempting to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume the "wget wget" in your post-commit file is a typo.)

For me your CentOS6 server has some network kernel issues.

Right now I am wondering which command prints "failed: Permission denied". I've never seen wget fail like that and it looks more like a local system failure (like open() system call failing).

To confirm such an issue, try doing wget to a different address, like google.com, as non root user. Does it work ?

Also use strace to find out more.

```
strace wget etc
```

and take note of the failing line.

If so, have you compiled your own kernel ? [Have you set CONFIG_ADROID_PARANOID_NETWORK to true](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.user-groups.slug.general/51624) ?

Note: for CSRF protected sites, you need to add extra parameters to download the crumb (this is defined in the [Subversion plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin).

Comment: Yes, it is a typo.  I'll fix that thank you for pointing it out.  I have not compiled my own kernel.  I will add the results of your suggestions once completed.  Thank for your help @coffeebreaks it is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting the error Error: strace: ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...): Permission denied when I use the command.

Comment: Your CentOS6 configuration is pretty restrictive to its users, either at configuration level, or using a security service like SELinux. Have you installed the system yourself ? Have you recompiled the kernel ? Have you added things like SELinux ? It for example allows you to disable tracing (read http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/49336.htm and http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinuxl). This now probably becomes a SELinux question and has probably nothing to do with svn, jenkins and subversive...

Comment: Yes, I installed the system myself.  No I didn't recompile the kernel, I've actually never recompiled a kernel before.  SELinux is installed because I've needed to allow changes.  After the information provided you are probably right that it is a system setup problem and not a SVN/Jenkins configuration problem.  Thank you for the help.  It was really late when I got your answer so I didn't see if recompiling the kernel worked.  Again really appreciate your understanding and help.  This is the furthest I've been able to get with figuring out what is happening.

Comment: It was SELinux.  I went in and changed it to permissive mode and I am getting http 200 ok as the return now from the script.  Again thank you so very much for your hep.  I will go learn more about SELinux now.  Since this is my personal home server I'm not to terribly worried about just leaving it in permissive mode for now.